# Unwanted blank lines between lists

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm having some trouble with some test code. This code is meant to:

- read a csv file
- take two inputs
- put the inputs in a list
- make a new list with the csv contents + the input list
- overwrite the csv with the new list.

  ```
  import csv

  input1 = input("input 1")
  input2 = input("input 2")

  original = []
  with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     original = list(reader)

  data = [input1,input2]
  original.append(data)

  with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerows(original)
  ```

For example, if 'cats' and 'dogs' were in the file, and I typed in 'zebras' and 'giraffes', I'd expect the csv to look like this when I open it in Notepad:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQSHA.jpg)

However blank lines are produced in between the lists when I run the code more than once, and I don't know why.
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acUVX.jpg)

I am new to Python and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to rstrip your input? For example, data = [input1.rstrip(), input2.rstrip()]

Comment: @user1157751 that makes no change

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
open('test.csv', 'w', newline='')
```

In new versions of Python `csv.Writer` now handles newline, but `open` also does. Then you must tell `open` that it must not add newline when writing to the file. See [API documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for more explanations.

Comment: thanks, I thought it would be something simple like that.

Comment: @Gabriel Owens, You are welcome, if it is the solution, you may accept it

Comment: What version of Python are you using? When I tried this, I got `TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`.